# Ubuntu crontab, same date, different executions

Tags: ubuntu, timezone, cron

Have three Ubuntu machines and a crontab which is executed like:

```
30 1 * * 1 /usr/local/bin/foo.sh
```

Two of the machines execute it at 01:30 but one machine execute it at 02:30 but I don't understand why.

On all three machines:

```
> date
Wed Mar 23 00:22:02 CET 2016

> cat /etc/timezones returns
Europe/Stockholm
```